# How can I add icon delete in image box after upload image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My html code is like this :

```
<input type='file' multiple/>
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) {

?>
    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>">
        <button  style="display: none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger show-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

My javascript code is like this :

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
        for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
        }        
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
    var IsImgAdded=false;
    $('.img-container').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
            $(this).append(imgTmpl);
            IsImgAdded=true;
            document.getElementsByClassName('show-button')[0].style.display = 'block';
        }
    });     
};
```

Demo and full code is like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gnfa-gf8h

Every time I upload an image, I want to put the delete icon in every image that is uploaded. For example I chose 2 images, then in every 2 images it will have delete icon

I had try it. But it only work in box 1. Otherwise the delete icon does not appear in the image. This seems to require more expertise about css. I'm not good in css

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line

`document.getElementsByClassName('show-button')[0].style.display = 'block';`

That will find the first `.show-button` and display it. To target each `.show-button` in an `.img-container` that has an image, change that line to `$(this).find('.show-button').show();`

Here's the updated function

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
        var IsImgAdded=false;
        $('.img-container').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
                $(this).append(imgTmpl);
                IsImgAdded=true;
                $(this).find('.show-button').show();
            }
        });     
    };
```

And to position the delete icon over the image, use absolute positioning.

```
.img-container { position: relative; }
.img-container .show-button { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Comment: Great. It works. But icon delete and image uploaded still separately. I want to put the delete icon in front of the uploaded image So one unit. This seems to require css expertise

Comment: @samueltoh add `.img-container { position: relative; } .img-container .show-button { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }`

Comment: @samueltoh awesome, no problem.

Comment: @samueltoh what's the problem? what do you need my help with exactly?

Comment: Yes. If you have free time, maybe you can help me. I've been asking since 6 hours ago. But there is no one who can help me. Maybe you can help me. If you want to help me, you can read my problem there